# С# Телеграмм(Telegram) получение координат

Tags: c#, telegram, геолокация

Есть проблема с получением координат от пользователя: когда он нажимает на `KeyboardButton.WithRequestLocation`, бот присылает ему его координаты, но  я не могу их получить ни через `update.Message.Location`, ни через `SendLocationAsync()`.

Код:

```cs
if (TextChat == "/start")
{
    if (update.Message.Location != null)
    {
        await client.SendLocationAsync(
            chatId: IdUser, update.Message.Location.Latitude, update.Message.Location.Longitude
        );

        Console.WriteLine($"lat: {update.Message.Location.Latitude}\nlon: {update.Message.Location.Longitude}");
        return;
    }

    ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new(new[] {
        KeyboardButton.WithRequestLocation("получение координат")
    })
    {
        ResizeKeyboard = true
    };
    Message sentMessage = await client.SendTextMessageAsync(
        chatId: IdUser, text: "кнопка готова    к работе!",
        replyMarkup: replyKeyboardMarkup, cancellationToken: token
    );
    
    await client.SendLocationAsync(
        chatId: IdUser, update.Message.Location.Latitude, 
        update.Message.Location.Longitude
    );
    
    Console.WriteLine($"lat: {update.Message.Location.Latitude}\nlon: {update.Message.Location.Longitude}");
```

Answer (score 1):

вопрос решился.  в самом начале кода фильтровал по Message типу  . а там другой тип . поэтому  не приходило... 20 часов потратил не зря. на проблему))